# C# Bond: string to wstring

Tags: bond

In the [Bond C# manual](http://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html), it notes the following:

> These following changes will break wire compatibility and are not recommended:
>
> - Adding or removing required fields
> - Incompatible change of field types (any type change not covered above); e.g.: int32 to string, string to wstring
> - ...

But it doesn't explain why.  The use case here is that I'm using Bond that connects a C# application with a C++ backend.  The field is currently a string.  I want to change it to a wstring.  The manual notes that C# strings can handle C++ strings and C++ wstrings.  Therefore, why I can't I just change the field type from string to wstring?  Why does this break wire compat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bond's binary formats, strings are UTF8 encoded (no BOM) and wstrings are UTF16-LE encoded. If you were to switch a field from string to wstring, the reading side would try to interpret UTF8 data as UTF16-LE data. These two encodings are not compatible with each other, hence a field type change from string to wstring is a breaking change.

Note that the manual says "For example C# `string` can represent either **Bond type** `string` or `wstring`." It does not say anything about C++ types. When working with Bond across C# and C++, there are *three* type systems: Bond's, C#'s, and C++'s.

If on the C++ side, you want to use something akin to `std::wstring` to store the field in memory, take a look as using [Custom type mapping](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cpp.html#custom-type-mappings) with the [string concept](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cpp.html#string-concept).